# GBQexception: How to read data with big query that is stored on google drive spreadsheet

Tags: pandas, google-api, google-drive-api, google-bigquery

I uploaded a dataset to bigquery via the google drive option and linking the google spreadsheet to a dataset which I call 'dim_table'

I then created a query to pull data from that dim_table dataset that I run daily.

I am trying to create an automated script that will run the same query code I created to get the dim_table data set and create a new dataset call chart_A

When I run this simple code:

```
import pandas_gbq as gbq
gbq.read_gbq("Select * from data.dim_stats",'ProjectID')
```

I get an error:

> GenericGBQException: Reason: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No
>   OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found.

I have been trying to read documentation on pandas gbq but could not find any documentation that points me on how I can authenticate gdrive with pandas gbq or use oauth. Any help is appreciated! :)

Let me know if you need me to comeup with a sample table online for testing.

best

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used pandas-gbq but authentication methods with BigQuery mentioned here [[1](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/authentication.html)].

1. Create  service account with a BigQuery role that can access to your datasets [[2](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating_a_service_account)].
2. Create and download the service account's JSON key [[3](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey)].
3. Set `the private_key` parameter to a file path to the JSON file or a string contains the JSON contents.

Also related guide to query Google Drive data without using pandas-gbq is here [[4](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#permanent-tables)].